# Can I list all active session ID's for a web app from a c# windows service?

Tags: c#, iis-7

We are time tracking users on an application and want to clock them out when they either log out or the session times out.  The log out is no problem and the session time out works about 95% of the time.  But 5% of the time either the Session_End is not getting called or I'm losing the user's session to pass their user ID to the database for clock out.

Below is my code in the Global.asax:

```
     protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var currentUser = Session[Constants.SessionKey_User] as User;

            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                //passes the user id to a db proc
                Utilities.LogTimeTrackingEvent(currentUser.UserId, Constants.TimeTrackingEntryTypes.Stop);   
             }         
        }
```

The thought is to setup a web service that polls the web server (IIS 7) every ten minutes for all active sessions and compares it against the session IDs stored in the database.  For all session IDs not in the list from the web server, clock those users out.  Is that plausible and does it sound like a reasonable approach?  Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be easier to figure out why Session_End is not being called.

Comment: Totally agree.  There seems to be very little pattern why it isn't being called and googling it didn't yield anything useful.

Comment: @JeffBorden: What are your app pool worker process recycling settings? By default it recycles every 1740 minutes? So that **can** occur while there are users connected, resulting in them losing their sessions. The session end event is not called, of course, when the worker process is restarted.

Comment: @thecoon: That's interesting.  The interval timeout is indeed 1740.  Is there a recommended way that I can perform a similar cleanup to the one I'm trying on Session_End?

Comment: @JeffBorden: Yes, usually this should be set to a time when you are relatively confident there will be no activity. Like at night, or early in the morning. Depends on the type of web site you're running. So it should be each day, at a fixed hour (usually).

Comment: Are the users staying idle for to long. this could be the reason you are losing their session id? You may have to set up a timer that lets them now their session is expiring and if they dont respond direct them to session_end at that point which will force them to log on again

Comment: Well, the server is supposed to log the time that the session_end times out (5 minutes in both session and formsauth config entries). Even setting the worker process to recycle in the middle of the night isn't working...